# Why am I getting "unexpected initializer before Mov" and "expected primary-expression before Act" when I initialize my struct arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble initializing my struct arrays in int main. I've already made my structs and a couple functions but I keep getting an "unexpected initializer before Mov" and "expected primary-expression before Act" error in int main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Date {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };
    
Date getCurrentDate(){
    Date d;
    time_t theTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);
    d.day   = aTime->tm_mday;
    d.month = aTime->tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
    d.year  = aTime->tm_year + 1900;

    return d;
}

struct Actor{
    string FName, LName, Location;
    char Gender;
    int ID, Age;
};

struct Movie{
    int ID, Day, Month, Year;
    string Name, Genre;
    double Gross;
    float Rating;
    char slash1, slash2;
};

struct Cast {
    int ActID;
    int MovID;
    string Role;
};

int main(){ 
int numMov, numAct, numCast, userchoice;
Actor Act[100], Movie Mov[100], Cast casts[100];
    return 0
}
```

Sorry, this is my first time posting here so I hope this makes sense. Fairly new to coding.

Comment: `Actor Act[100], Movie Mov[100], Cast casts[100];` is valid syntax, just as `int foo, double bar;` isn't

Comment: When you run into a problem, see if you can remove a complication. For example, if you are having trouble with "my struct arrays", try simplifying to "my structs" (drop the "array" aspect). If the problem persists, congratulations, you've removed a red herring! If the problem goes away, look for another way to simplify (maybe "my int arrays", dropping the "struct" aspect). In this case, the first simplification would lead to `Actor Act, Movie Mov, Cast casts;` -- does this line compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numMov, numAct, numCast, userchoice; //coma works since numMov, numAct, numCast, userchoice are all of same type int
Actor Act[100];
Movie Mov[100]; 
Cast casts[100];
```

When you define multiple variables of same type you can separate names by coma (exactly what you did with int variables). Ohterwise each variable with unique type like Actor, Movie, Cast arrays should be defined with semicolon after each definition. If you put them in one line separated by semicolon this will work.

Comment: Just a follow up. This worked but is there a particular reason why putting each array in a separate line worked?